# How to find the chord $CD$?

Tags: geometry

[image]

So this is the question. And the answer is $10 \ cm$. I cannot see a way out. Is similarity to be used? Or there will be a construction? Please guide me.

Comment: $PA\cdot PB=PC\cdot PD\iff8(8+4)=6(6+CD)\iff CD=10.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove triangle $ADP$ and $CBP$ are similar.(because $\widehat{APC}=\widehat{APC}$ and $\widehat{BCP}=\widehat{DAP}$). Therfore we have:
$$\frac{PB}{PD}=\frac{PA}{PC}\Rightarrow \frac{8}{6}=\frac{6+CD}{12}\Rightarrow CD=10$$

Comment: Short and simple!